# run task on node and restart deamon from different node if task failed Ansible

Tags: automation, ansible, ansible-2.x

One of the task is to run a curl command on node[A,B,C] and failed it if a speficic string isn't present. If failed, I want to rescue by running an application restart on app[A,B,C]. nodeA ==> appA . nodeB ==> appB . nodeC ==> appC

```
[group1]
nodeA
nodeB
nodeC

[group2]
appA
appB
appC



- hosts: group1
  serial: 1    #I want to do it one at a time

  tasks:
    -name: find if app is running
     command: curl example.com
     register: curl_result
     failed_when: 'version' not in curl_result

- hosts: group2
  tasks:
    - name: restart deamon
      service: app_deamon
      state: restarted
```

Currently, this restart all deamon under group2.

It's important the restart task run against the right hosts, if nodeA task failed appA service should be the one that gets restart, and not appB or appC.Thanks in advance for any help on this

Answer (score 1):

You could add a host variable for each host in the inventory do indicate its dedicated "rescue host". For example:

```
[group1]
nodeA rescue_host=appA
nodeB rescue_host=appB
nodeC rescue_host=appC
```

Then in your play delegate the rescue task based on the `rescue_host` variable:

```
- block:
    - name: find if app is running
      command: curl example.com
      register: curl_result
      failed_when: 'version' not in curl_result
  rescue:
    - <task>: <restart application>
      delegate_to: "{{ rescue_host }}"
```

Comment: I cannot touch the inventory file. since it's dynamically generated. and I don't have to use the rescue module, any other way to achieve the same result is fine. Thanks for looking